# Ember get data from MongoDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

I have a MongoDB server which has a NodeJS server to interact with it. I want Ember Store to get data from this server. A tutorial has led me until this point but it does not work for me ([tutorial](http://ryanchristiani.com/working-with-ember-data-node-express-and-mongodb/)), I think it is outdated but I am not sure. 
This part of the backend server is about sending data:

```
app.get('/api/appointments', function(req, res){
    AppointmentModel.find({}, function(err, docs){
        if(err) res.send({error:err});
        else res.send({data:docs, "type":"appointment"});
    });
});
```

A curl request proves that it does work:

```
curl http://localhost:4500/api/appointments
{"data":[{"flags":[],"dates":[],"invited":[],"_id":"5adc8b6724a69f4327c4c7af","author":7,"title":"Does this work"}],"type":"appointment"}
```

This is the part of the ember code that makes the request to the server:

```
export default Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('appointment');
    }
});
```

This is the error I get in the console of the webbrowser(chrome):

```
Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: Encountered a resource object with an undefined type (resolved resource using (unknown mixin)) Error: Assertion Failed: Encountered a resource object with an undefined type (resolved resource using (unknown mixin))
    at new EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:24475:25)
    at Object.assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:24725:15)
    at Class._normalizeResourceHelper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85052:61)
    at Class._normalizeDocumentHelper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:84993:25)
    at Class._normalizeResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85121:36)
    at Class.normalizeArrayResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:86013:19)
    at Class.normalizeFindAllResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85873:19)
    at Class.normalizeResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85816:23)
    at normalizeResponseHelper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76037:39)
    at promise.then.adapterPayload (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76889:19)
```

Because the error is something about types I checked and checked again the models but did not find anything that would give an error.
Ember:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.attr('number'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    flags: DS.hasMany('number'),
    dates: DS.hasMany('date'),
    invited: DS.hasMany('number')
});
```

NodeJS/Mongo:

```
//The schema for appointments
var appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: Number, //Userid of the owner of the appointment.
    title: String,
    description: String,
    flags: [Number], //Array of ids of flags that are set.
    dates: [Date],
    invited: [Number] //Array of user ids.
});
var AppointmentModel = mongoose.model('appointment', appointmentSchema);
```

In what special way does ember need the data in order to correcly handle it?

I have read some docs about store and ember but I am still new to the framework, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Debugging tip: " return this.store.findAll('appointment');" instead of this try "return {"author":"John"}". You can try out various JSONs to debug.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand ember datas model definitions. This does not make sense:

```
flags: DS.hasMany('number'),
```

this basically means *an appointments has multiple flags and they are of the model `number`. you can not use `hasMany` or `belongsTo` for arrays or primitive types.

Now you have two options. Either you create models for flags, people (invited), etc, or you return simple JSON structures. For this specify `attr()` (no argument given).

Your next problem is that by default ember assumes [`jsonapi`](http://jsonapi.org/), but you're not sending `jsonapi`. Here you can either move to `jsonapi` on your server, or you modify your [serializer](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.Serializer) as written [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/models/customizing-serializers/).

---

However with all this in mind it comes to my conclusion that you maybe dont want to use `ember-data` at all. `ember-data` is very useful for data that has relations and is based on models, but you can use `ember` without it.

You just can just do this:

```
model() {
  return $.getJSON('/api/appointments');
}
```

and then operate on the plain JSON you're sending.

**If you want to use `ember-data` or not depends totally on your use-case.**

Comment: Also probably best practice to avoid jquery and use ember-fetch now: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see you're using the wrong adapter, your backend is using the JSONAPI specification http://jsonapi.org/, but ember is expecting REST, that's why the type property is failing, you just need to change the adapter from REST to JSONAPI, here you can find more info https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/ it should be pretty simple in your case just change the adapter to JSONAPIAdapter